# C# Reading one or more integer values and assigning an object certain enum attributes based on the integers read

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I am having a small problem, and I cant seem to find an answer anywhere. I will try to keep it short and clear

I have a class called exercises, which has an enum responsible for what body parts the exercise hits. Lets say we have

```
Chest = 1
Shoulders = 2
Arms = 4
Legs = 8
Back = 16
```

So far my class "exercise" has a name, and this enum. In theory, this should result in having something like "Bech press - chest, arms n/ Deadlift - back, legs" and so on.

Next I have a class Catalog, that holds all the exercises, and in that class a method, called AddExercise. Here is the code snippet:

```
    public void AddExercise()
    {
        Exercise ToAdd = new Exercise();
        Console.WriteLine("What is the name of the exercise?");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        ToAdd.name = name;
        katalog.Add(ToAdd);
    }
```

What I want to do know, is include "What muscle groups does the exercise hit?", and then a multichoice with mentioned muscle groups. My idea is that it would look something like this:

```
1. Chest
2. Shoulders
3. Arms
4. Legs
5. Back
6. That is all
```

**As long as the person kept choosing 1-5 the exercise would acquire the enum attributes, and then quit the loop once the person chose 6, but I have no idea how to do this part. From most Ive seen about enums they are mostly used in the string format and parsing, so I have no idea how to assign attributes by reading integer. And the hardest part is assigning several of them.**

Here is my enum, by the way:

```
[Flags]
public enum BodyParts : int
{
    None = 0,
    Chest = 1,
    Shoulders = 2,
    Biceps = 4,
    Triceps = 8,
    Back = 16,
    Legs = 32
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What frontend tech are you using? MVC or WPF or WinForm?

Comment: Whatever tech you are using this is somewhat a little more than simple. You can get your enum list by Enum.GetNames(typeof(BodyParts)).ToDictionary(n => n, n => Enum.Parse(typeof(BodyParts), n));

Comment: And add frontend logic to use a value to do multi-binding (WPF) or computedValue (angular/ko.js in MVC) to map flag values. Say, Chest | Shoulders == 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a lookup table connecting string answer to enum values

```
    var lookup = new Dictionary<string,BodyParts > () {
{ "chest" , BodyParts .Chest},
{ "shoulders " , BodyParts .Shoulders}
...
};
```

and use it like this

```
string name = Console.ReadLine().ToLower;
var bodypart = BodyParts.None;
lookup.TryGetValue(name, out bodypart);
katalog.Add(bodypart));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CheckedListBox` where the items are the instances of the enum.

```
 var clb = new CheckedListBox();    
 foreach (BodyParts bp in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BodyParts)))
            clb .Items.Add(bp);
```

Then to get the flagged combination of all checked items, just `bitwise or` (combine them).  The result will be a bitmask that has all the selected body parts.

```
var result = clb.CheckedItems
              .Cast<BodyParts>()
              .Aggregate(BodyParts.None,     
                (current, bp) => current | bp);
```